# Unable to access buckets through NPM's @google-cloud/storage package

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am attempting to resize images as they are added to Firebase storage. I am using the code from this repo as a template, but it looks like some of it is outdated since December of 2017. https://github.com/academind/firebase-cloud-functions-introduction/blob/01-storage/functions/index.js

Also the subject matter of the following youtube code-along, so I know this code worked at some point. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGsmWKMMiYs

Firebase's big issue is with line #2

```
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
```

It says that "require(...) is not a function". So I removed the invocation and decided to work with whatever error that caused. I had to change several things around to make everything fit the current state of the API, but I ended up with this block of code and this error

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const spawn = require('child-process-promise').spawn;

exports.onFileChange= functions.storage.object().onFinalize(event => {
    const bucket = event.bucket;
    const contentType = event.contentType;
    const filePath = event.name;
    console.log('File change detected, function execution started');

if (event.resourceState === 'not_exists') {
    console.log('We deleted a file, exit...');
    return;
}

if (path.basename(filePath).startsWith('resized-')) {
    console.log('We already renamed that file!');
    return;
}

const destBucket = gcs.bucket(bucket); // <------------------
    const tmpFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), path.basename(filePath));
    const metadata = { contentType: contentType };
    return destBucket.file(filePath).download({
        destination: tmpFilePath
    }).then(() => {
        return spawn('convert', [tmpFilePath, '-resize', '500x500', tmpFilePath]);
    }).then(() => {
        return destBucket.upload(tmpFilePath, {
            destination: 'resized-' + path.basename(filePath),
            metadata: metadata
        })
    });
});
```

TypeError: gcs.bucket is not a function

My issue is that I can't invoke "require('@google-cloud/storage')" because require isn't a function. But I can't invoke gcs either because gcs is not a function. Google's own documentation still says to require its storage module this way. https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/Bucket Now I don't know how to approach this.

Comment: Can you verify which version of `@google-cloud/storage` is in your package.json?

Comment: That would be "@google-cloud/storage": "^2.0.3"

Comment: There was a breaking API change in 2.0.0.  You have to use it differently (or perhaps force the version back down to 1.7, or use the admin sdk).

Comment: Oh, that's perfect. I downgraded to version 1.7 and everything works perfectly